# List search by index?

Tags: c#, list, search, indexing

I'm trying to search for the *index* of the first *list item*, which has the value **"hello"** and it's *index* is higher than **15**.
This is apparently not the way, because when I refer to *p*, I refer to the **value**, not the *string* itself (IndexOf looks up the index of the first occurence of **"hello"** in the list, because **p == string**)

```
int soucasny = list1.FindIndex(p => p == "hello" || list1.IndexOf(p) > 15);
```

Is there a way to achieve the desired result? Select probably?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can specify a start index for [`IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s8t42k5w(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
int soucasny = list1.IndexOf("hello", 15);
```

Comment: I think this will not work, no? As the object inside the list is not the same as the constant string you are passing, no?

Comment: Oh yes, it will. I think so. Testing it now.

Comment: @Jauch why not? strings are compared by their values. This code does the same thing with OP's code. if he is not looking for exact match this should be speficied in the question

Comment: Yes, I was in doubt if inside the list it would work, but I tested and yes, it works :)
The only problem this method have is if the list has less than 16 items...

Comment: It does and very well. No need to use FindIndex and such. In this case, it's my fault, not knowing IndexOf has an overload which takes 2 arguments. Three, even. Missed this somehow. Thank you.

Comment: pass the arguments as a variable then can you not do something like this
`var lstCount = list1.Count()` then pass it into your function
`int soucasny = list1.IndexOf("should be a variable", lstCount);`

Answer (score 2):

Use [`List<T>.FindIndex Method (Int32, Predicate<T>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/efasdh0s(v=vs.110).aspx) which takes a predicate and specifies the index to start search like:

```
int soucasny = list1.FindIndex(15, p => p == "hello");
```

If you have `List<string>` then using `List<T>.IndexOf` would give you the result, but if you have a list of custom objects then you may need predicate. Like:

```
List<Student> studentList = new List<Student>();
int index = studentList.FindIndex(15, p=> p.StudentName == "Some Name");
```

Answer (score 1):

@Selman22 provides the most correct and efficient answer for your exact question.  I offer the following merely as an addendum, for cases where you may have a non-`List` sequence or need access to an element's index from within your filter expression:

```
public static int FirstIndexWhere<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> sequence,
    Func<T, int, bool> predicate)
{
    if (sequence == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("sequence");
    if (predicate == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("predicate");

    var index = 0;

    for (var enumerator = sequence.GetEnumerator(); enumerator.MoveNext(); ++index)
    {
        if (predicate(enumerator.Current, index))
            return index;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Example usage:

```
int soucasny = list1.FirstIndexWhere((p, i) => p == "hello" && i > 15);
```